# I am trying to solve a linear equation but I keep getting the error 'last 2 dimensions of the array must be square'

Tags: python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
def non_LUT_decode(M,V): 

    M=np.array(M)
    V=np.array(V)


    x=np.array([])
    x=np.linalg.solve(M,V)
    x=x.astype(bool)
```

Comment: What is your input?